# PHP: Changing atributes through included function

Tags: php, class, function, flash, embed

I'm pretty new to classes and functions, so I'm working with a simple script which embeds a Youtube video and a local swf. It works fine, but I'm unable to change the $width and $height attributes in the swf. If I create them inside the function I have to set the value to '0', thus not being updated by the external value. It will remain as 0.

There are two files:

classMedia.php

```
<?php
/*Gabriel*/
class Media {

    public function embedYT($code){
        echo "<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$code." ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        }

        public function embedSWF ($swf){
        $width='0';
        $height='0';
    echo "<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0' ID=objects WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80> 
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE=".$swf." '> 
<EMBED src=".$swf." ' WIDTH=".$width." HEIGHT=".$height." TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' PLUGINSPAGE='http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash'> 
</OBJECT>";
    } }
    ?>
```

And the output 
demo.php

```
<?php include "classMedia.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
$media = new Media();
 $code = "XSGBVzeBUbk";
$media-> embedYT($code);
?>

<?php 
$media = new Media();
 $swf = "test.swf";
 $height = "360";
 $width = "480";
$media-> embedSWF($swf);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `embedSWF` function to add two parameters to it, respectively `$width` and `$height`, like this:

```
public function embedSWF ($swf, $width = '0', $height = '0'){
    echo "<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0' ID=objects WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80> 
            <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE=".$swf." '> 
            <EMBED src=".$swf." ' WIDTH=".$width." HEIGHT=".$height." TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' PLUGINSPAGE='http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash'> 
        </OBJECT>";
}
```

Then, call it like this:

```
<?php 
$media = new Media();
 $swf = "test.swf";
 $height = "360";
 $width = "480";
$media-> embedSWF($swf, $width, $height);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `$height` and `$width` are only relevant for the `embedSWF()` method (and I suspect this as it does not look like the dimensions are associated with the `Media` *instance* but to the `embedSWF()` *method call*), you should add them along with the `$swf` argument:

```
public function embedSWF ($swf, $width = 0, $height = 0) {
    echo "<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0' ID=objects WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE=".$swf." '><EMBED src=".$swf." ' WIDTH=".$width." HEIGHT=".$height." TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' PLUGINSPAGE='http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash'></OBJECT>";
}
```

Called like so:

```
<?php 
$media = new Media();
 $swf = "test.swf";
$media-> embedSWF($swf, 480, 360);
?>
```

---

**EDIT**
In general, you should add attributes to the class when they express or relate to the *state of the current instance (object)*. E.g.,

```
public class Media {
    private $swf;
    private $height;
    private $width;

    public __construct($swf, $height, $width) {
        $this->swf = $swf;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public getEmbedCode() {
        // ...
    }

    public getIframeCode() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the above, a `Media` instance has a *state* (an SWF with dimension) which can be output in different formats. I.e., the method transforms the internal state to an output.

Alternatively, we have a "utility-like" class with no state. Instead it holds a set of methods which works exclusively on passed data (parameters). E.g.,

```
public class Media {
    public embedSWF($swf, $height, $width) {
        // ...
    }

    public embedYT($code) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the widht and height as parameters to your function like so

```
$height = "360";
$width = "480";
$media-> embedSWF($swf, width, height);
```

then change your function to look like this

`public function embedSWF ($swf, width, height)`

and remove your initiation of width and height in your function.

Your width and height are currently out of the objects scope.

Comment: With this method, he should always pass the `width` and `height` parameters. Besides your `width` and `height` should be respectively `$width` and `$height`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$width` and `$height` to object attributes like so:

```
<?php
/*Gabriel*/
class Media {
    public $width  = 0;
    public $height = 0;

    public function embedYT($code){
        echo "<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$code." ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    }

    public function embedSWF ($swf){
        echo "<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0' ID=objects WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80> 
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE=".$swf." '> 
<EMBED src=".$swf." ' WIDTH=".$this->width." HEIGHT=".$this->height."     TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' PLUGINSPAGE='http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave    /download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash'> 
</OBJECT>";
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
<?php 
    $media = new Media();
    $code = "XSGBVzeBUbk";
    $media-> embedYT($code);
?>

<?php 
    $media = new Media();
    $swf = "test.swf";
    $media->height = 360;
    $media->width = 480;
    $media-> embedSWF($swf);
?>
```

Comment: Surely this still wont work because width and height are still not passed to the object in any way, width and height in your example will still be 0. - Your update fixes my comment :P

Comment: I added the usage example. When you set `$media->height = 360;` the height is passed to the object.